# Convert JAXB class (not its object) to xml template

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there way one can convert JAXB class (not its object) to xml template.

For example

Below code is taken from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/jaxb-generate-xml-xsd.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
    {

        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

        UserT user = factory.createUserT();
        user.setUserName("Sanaulla");
        ItemT item = factory.createItemT();
        item.setItemName("Seagate External HDD");
        item.setPurchasedOn("August 24, 2010");
        item.setAmount(new BigDecimal("6776.5"));

        ItemListT itemList = factory.createItemListT();
        itemList.getItem().add(item);

        ExpenseT expense = factory.createExpenseT();
        expense.setUser(user);
        expense.setItems(itemList);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
        JAXBElement element = factory.createExpenseReport(expense);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output",Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(element,System.out);
    }
```

In above code object of class Element has been create to marshall. My question is what if I don't have object of JAXB class, will I still be able to generate xml template (with no values)

Comment: Why wouldn't you have an object instance?

Comment: I want to convert jaxb type to xml template during runtime. If I will create an object then I have to populate it. I just need to generate xml template

Comment: So why not just set `nillable=true` in your XML elements and just instantiate an empty object with all values set to null?

Comment: I have xsd's from which JAXB types are generated. I can't make changes to xsd and set things to null.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want without having an object in which to marshal. The XML binding is going to be based on object data, so you will have to have one in order to generate your XML. I would suggest, if you're worried about populating an object each time, that you create a Factory of some sort, with a `newObject()` or similar method that will give you a populated object, and you can (if you are so inclined), post-process the generated XML to give you an "empty" template. Your XSD's are going to prevent you from having a "valid" XML template anyway.